During debug vb.net script, the code becomes c#
I have a VB.net script and I want to debug it. For do this I attach the debug to a Windows application.I have setted some brakpoints in the script, but when the script recive them, the IDE makes a new file in C:\Users\LocalUser\AppData\Local\Temp.vsdbgsrc and the file code is in C#.What I have to set for haveing the debug file in VB.net? I have searched a lot but no luck.

Why are you attaching to a process instead of running the code from VS?

Make sure you have the .pdb file in the same folder where the application is loading the assembly.  Otherwise, Visual Studio will use its built-in ILSpy to decompile to C#.  It may be helpful to look at the loaded modules view, which will show which modules have debug symbols loaded.

Firstly, there's no such thing as a VB.NET script. You can have a VBScript script, because it's a scripting language, but VB.NET is not, so VB.NET code is not a script. Secondly, if you have the code then you should be running the project directly in the debugger, not attaching the debugger once the project is running. If you only have a compiled assembly then that's very different. It's not VB at all and it will be decompiled into C#. It would help if you could provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem, which you haven't.

I have a external program, than calls the script to perform internal actions. The script is written as a class in the vb.net IDE and then called by the external program. If I want to debug the class\script I attach the debug to the external program. All works fine, but the type of code debugged is not the same I wrote the script\class.

@Craig I have tried to copy the pdb file in the same folder, but still no luck.

In my experience, if having the PDB there isn't working, then most likely there's some kind of mismatch between the PDB and the code---but that would probably also mean that your breakpoint was at a higher level and you tried to step in.  If you set a breakpoint in the VB code, then you should see VB when the debugger breaks.  (And if you can't set a breakpoint, it should tell you why.)

There is no option for the debugger to use VB.Net. Both C# and VB.Net are compiled to the same IL (intermediate language). This IL is the real code given the to the JIT for producing the code actually run by the CPU, and IL and the JIT neither know nor care about the original language. But for some time now the JIT and most of the CLR themselves have been written in C#, and that's what the debugger sees and knows to generate.
But even with C#, you will not get back the same code your wrote initially, because of a concept called "Lowering"
